# How to see the continuing 8-bit grayscale image data flow from USB port?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

So, I have a continuous data flow coming thorugh the COM4 port on Windows. I am reading the data with this code:

```
import serial
import cv2
from time import sleep

ser = serial.Serial ("COM4", 115200)    
while True:
    received_data = ser.read()              
    sleep(0.03)
    data_left = ser.inWaiting()             
    a=cv2.imread(received_data,0)
    cv2.imshow("Image",a)
    print (received_data)
```

the openCV part does not work and spyder gives this error:

```
TypeError: bad argument type for built-in operation
```

If I take the openCV part out I am able to see bytes like this:

```
b'AA\x00A::\x00A:A\x00AA:\x00A:A\x00A:A\x00:A:\x00A:AAA::AAA\x00AAA\x00A::\x00:AA\x00:::\x00AAA\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00::A\x00A::A::::A::A:A\x00AAA\x00A::\x00AA:\x00:A:\x00::A\x00AAA\x00A:A\x00:A:\x00:A:\x00::AAA::::A:A::\x00AA:\x00:::\x00AAA\x00::A\x00:AA\x00:AA\x00::A\x00:::\x00:A:\x00A::AAAA:A:AAA:\x00A::\x00:AA\x00AAA\x00:::\x00:A:\x00AAA\x00AAA\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00::AA:\x00A::\x00:A:\x00:::\x00:::\x00AAA\x00:::\x00:A:\x00:A:\x00A:3\x00AAAAA:A:::AA::\x00::A\x00A::\x00A:A\x00:::\x00:::\x00::A\x00:::\x00A::\x00:AA\x00AA:AA::AAAA:::\x00::A\x00AA:\x00A::\x00:A:\x00:AA\x00A::\x00AA:\x00AA:\x00:AA\x00:A:\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00A\x00:::\x00AA:\x00:AA\x00:A:\x00AAA\x00:::\x00A::\x00A::\x00AAAA:AAA:A\x00:AA\x00A::\x00:AA\x00:::\x00:A:\x00A:A'
```

This data is 8-bit grayscale image data. How can I see the continuous data flow ( kind of like a grayscale video) with python?

This is the raw 8-bit grayscale image data coming from an FPGA. The dimensions are 160*120 and the starting bit is 0 and the stopping bit is 1

Comment: You're going to need to know the shape (i.e. dimensions) of the image.

Comment: How can I understand that? Does it have anything to do with the resolution? If we assume that I know the dimension what should I do?

Comment: yes, you will probably have to see where an image starts and where it ends and you need to know the format, so for example if it is RGB raw data you have to do different thinfs than if it's a jpeg image

Comment: It is a 8-bit raw grayscale image data and its resolution is 160x120 What does this refer to as a numpy array?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will need to look something like this but it is untested as I don't have your image source.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

while True:

    bytesBuffer = read and accumulate 160*120 bytes from serial

    # Make bytes buffer into Numpy array and reshape
    frame =  np.frombuffer(bytesBuffer, dtype=np.uint8).reshape((120,160))

    cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
    cv2.waitKey(30)
```

You will need to somehow know when the frame begins so you know when you have the top-left pixel.

You may need to swap the 120 and 160. As it is, it assumes height is 120 pixels and width is 160 pixels.

The problem with your code is that `cv2.imread()` expects a file that contains a JPEG/PNG encoded image, rather than the raw bytes you are currently giving it.

You could usefully share a buffer of 160x120 bytes of data in your question, or provide some serial code that sends an image in the same way as your source.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for answering my question. I am new to FPGA's, ad I am using an FPGA that is connected to a camera so I don't know when the picture starts really. But the FPGA sends bytes when I turn on a switch, so I may not need a starting bit representation.

Comment: So, I send 0 as starting bit and 1 as stopping bit

Comment: Ok, my code above should work with that scenario. If it doesn't, please gather the first 120*160 bytes and save them in a file and share it via Dropbox or Google Drive or somesuch and I'll work out how to display it for you.

Comment: Note that if you do share a file it should be written as **binary** and exactly 19,200 bytes long.

Comment: I've realized that my image actually has 640*480 resolution. So, I am going to send you a file which has 307,200 bytes

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Sefu6DaQUXm70zgs-lX0BWTny5qS6z4m/view?usp=sharing This is the file I created

Comment: I have done some fairly comprehensive analysis of your data and can't find anything very sensible in there. I think your reading of the data via serial is maybe causing problems. Can you click `edit` under your original question and add in the code you actually use to read the data please? Have you tried `received_data = ser.read(640*480)` ?

Comment: I don't know much about hardware, but if you have space on your FPGA, you might consider adding an option to generate a *"test"* image the same size as your camera produces but something identifiable like a greyscale ramp from 0..255 either across or down the image, or make each line of the image a white bar on a black background where the length of the bar is the row number.